# Need Material design color pallette,

Tags: color, corel-draw, google-material-design

I want to Draw some icons in Material Design, I was thinking if there is any Material Design color pallette available for Corel Draw,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Corel Draw can import Adobe Color Files (`.aco`), so you should be able to use these colour palettes from Google Design Resources:

> https://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/color-palettes.html

Comment: That's a 404 - this works, though: https://www.google.com/design/spec/resources/color-palettes.html

Comment: I can open that `.aco` in CorelDRAW X6, but the resulting "Adobe Photoshop Palette" lacks the color names and numbers, such as "Red 500", from the [material design color specs](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette).

The imported palette just shows the RGB values: for example, "R243 G66 B54" (#F34236); which, by the way, doesn't match any of the colors in the material design palette.